# Ruby on Rails 4 Rspec, Capybara Doesn't See Button

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, capybara, rspec3

Capybara doesn't seem to see button on my webpage. Here you have my testing code

```
  before(:each) do
    @inspiring = PostMotivation.create(:title => "This is title",:body => "body main content",:short => "short content of this post",:date => "20.06.2014")
  end

  it "should redirect when you want to add new comment" do
    visit "/inspiring"
    click_button("add_comment")
  end
```

And here you can see my views:

```
<%= button_to new_main_dupa_path(0,0,@post_to_render3.id), class: "button",id: "add_comment" do %>
        Add new comment!
<% end %>
```

The error is:

```
  2) Testing inspiring subpage with integration tests should redirect when you want to add new comment
     Failure/Error: click_button("add_comment")
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find button "add_comment"
     # ./spec/features/inspiring.rb:39:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

How to make capybara see this button?
I just couldn't find solution to this problem, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, mistake was of course made by me, I forgot that by visit "/inspiring", you are visiting posts list, and to add comment you have to actually visit particular post to be able to add any comments, so passing code should look like this.

```
  it "should redirect when you want to add new comment" do
    visit "/inspiring"
    click_link("inspiring_#{@inspiring.id}")
    click_button("add_comment")
  end
```